# How to write an SQL statement to record the fact that Rabbit has one additional homework assigned

Tags: sql

I have a table shown below, and I want to record the fact that `Rabbit` has one `additional homework` assigned.

```
id |name     |partnerId |totalHW |lateHW |major 
-----------------------------------------------
12 |Puma     |17        |3       |0      |CS 
14 |Rabbit   |21        |7       |4      |SE 
17 |Mouse    |12        |5       |5      |CE 
21 |Aardvark |32        |2       |0      |CS 
22 |Cougar   |24        |4       |2      |SE 
24 |Zebra    |28        |7       |3      |EE 
27 |Orca     |14        |2       |1      |CS 
32 |Elephant |null      |0       |null   |S
```

How do I go about it? I could not find the relation as how is `Rabbit` assigned one additional homework. How to solve this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
UPDATE [tablename]
SET totalHW = totalHW + 1
WHERE name = 'Rabbit';
```

Comment: I could not interpret what was desired in the question. So does it mean that I have to update the table in such a way that Rabbit gets one more assignment? If my interpretation is correct, then your answer seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely come to a solution easily if you change to a normalized database structure.  "totalHW" and "lateHW" are calculated fields based on other data, i.e., individual assignments. Instead create a homework table, likely with a late field and whatever other fields, and when you need to know total and number of late, calculate that in sql. Once you do that, adding more homework and other manipulation of the data becomes very simple.